# Clarifying the definition of continuity at a point in Johnsonbaugh/Pfaffenberger Foundations of Mathematical Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

In my copy of Foundations of Mathematical Analysis, in the section on continuity, I'm not understanding definition 33.1. The definition is as follows:

Let $f$ be a function from a subset *X* of **R** into **R**. We say that $f$ is continuous at *a* if either:

- *a* is an accumulation point of *X* and $ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$
- *a* is not an accumulation point of *X*.

I don't understand the second bullet point. If *a* is not an accumulation point of *X*, then can't it be that *a* is not in the domain of *f* ? If that is the case, why would we say that *f* is continuous at *a* ? I can't see how it could vacuously be the case that *f* is continuous there. Perhaps is the definition simply missing a stipulation that $ a \in X$ ? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the first bullet point: it says that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$. If $a\notin X$, then how is $f(a)$ defined? So in my opinion, in both cases the author meant to take $a\in X$.

Comment: Any way that I think of it makes it that the author must have meant that $a \in X$ at the start, but I wasn't sure if there are perhaps weird edge cases where we might want to say that _f_ is continuous at all points not in its domain. My concern is that if _a_ is neither in _X_ nor an accumulation point of _X_ it would make _f_ continuous at _a_ because you would refer to the second bullet point. If it's just a mistake on the textbook's part then that's alright, I just don't want to jump to that conclusion immediately. Thanks!

Comment: Personally I've never seen continuity properties of a function outside its domain being referred to. One might talk about functions that are extendable to continuous functions over a larger domain, but still, that requires an extension of the domain. I'm a student though so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: Hmm I guess I'll just assume that the text meant to specify $a \in X$ since that goes along more nicely with other formulations I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you need $a\in X$. Otherwise, there is no meaning in the continuity of $f$ outside of $X$. Consider $X=\{0\}\cup [1,2]$. Then $0\in X$ is no accumulation point of $X$. Hence, by definition $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow how the example illustrates that there would be no meaning to continuity of _f_ outside of _X_. I sort of understand that we let singletons like 0 in your example be vacuously continuous. If 0 weren't in X then, we would say that asking if _f_ is continuous at 0 is meaningless since continuity only makes sense on the domain?

Comment: The example illustrates a set $X$ with a non-accumulation point. By definition, any function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is continuous at $0$.

Comment: Right, but _a_ is a non-accumulation point and in _X_. My concern is if _a_ is a non-accumulation point and not in _X_, since this definition leaves open that possibility. For example, let $X = [1,2]$. Then _a_ = 0 is not an accumulation point of _X_. Would we say that _f_ is continuous at _a_ = 0 or do we need to add to the above definition that in fact $a \in X$ ?

Comment: You definitely need $a\in X$. The definition should be like this: Let be $a\in X$. If $a$ is an accumulation point of $X$ and ... , then ... . If $a$ is not an accumulation point of $X$, then ... .

Comment: Ah okay, thanks!